# cbind Truncates Cell Value With Dot Dash

Tags: r

Using `cbind()`, I am combining the data which has elements with `dot` or `dash` in the cell values. `cbind()` seems to truncate anything before this `dot`.

For example: If the cell values is `XYZ.1`, the after `cbind()` it's `1`. And, if values is `XYZ-02`, then after `cbind()` it becomes `2`.

**Data**

```
  A       B       C
ABC.1   XYZ-02  PQR-03
ABC.1   XYZ-02  PQR-03
ABC.1   XYZ-02  PQR-03
ABC.1   XYZ-02  PQR-03
ABC.1   XYZ-02  PQR-03
```

**Code**

```
data <- cbind(Data$A, Data$B)
```

**Output**

```
A   B   
1   2
1   2
1   2
1   2
1   2
```

**Ideal Output**

```
  A       B   
ABC.1   XYZ-02
ABC.1   XYZ-02
ABC.1   XYZ-02
ABC.1   XYZ-02
ABC.1   XYZ-02
```

What is the reason for this to happen? Thanks.

Comment: Is `Data`  data frame or data.table? Try str(Data) and posting the output here.

Comment: @sconfluentus - It is a `data.frame` and below accepted answer works.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try,

```
data = cbind.data.frame(df$A, df$B)
```

This will yield your desired output,

```
A        B
1 ABC.1 XYZ-02
2 ABC.1 XYZ-02
3 ABC.1 XYZ-02
4 ABC.1 XYZ-02
```

Comment: Except that's not the output it gives - this code names the columns like `Data$A` and `Data$B`.

Comment: @thelatemail - That's fine. I can handle column header later on, unless there is a way to do it within `cbind.data.frame()`, then it can save time.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil - you don't need `cbind` at all. See my answer.

Comment: Otherwise, if you were pulling from two different data.frame's, I would use `cbind(Data1["A"], Data2["B"])` which will automatically dispatch to `cbind.data.frame`

Answer (score 11):

This is just a selection,

```
Data[c("A","B")]
#      A      B
#1 ABC.1 XYZ-02
#2 ABC.1 XYZ-02
#3 ABC.1 XYZ-02
#4 ABC.1 XYZ-02
#5 ABC.1 XYZ-02
```

The issue is because you are dealing with `factor` variables inside `Data` that are stored internally as integers, rather than character strings.

```
cbind(
  factor(c("a","a")),
  factor(c("a","a"),levels=c("b","a"))
)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    1    2
```

...replicates your result. Trying to `cbind` two factors will result in everything being coerced back to a matrix containing integers.

Comment: One wonders where so many newbs get the idea that cbind needs to be used frequently. My hypothesis is that insufficient time is spent on teaching how to use lists.

Answer (score 2):

The columns are in the same data frame. use `dplyr::select` to pull the columns you want:

```html
Data %>% dplyr::select(c(A,B))
```

Comment: .@cephalopod - I want to avoid `dplyr`, as I will be moving the code to `TERR`. It doesn't support it well.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil in that case use base function, `Data[,c("A", "B")]`